WARNING: /etc/chkrootkit.conf is deprecated. Please put your settings in /etc/chkrootkit/chkrootkit.conf instead
I just went through a few hundred messages in root's mail, there were plenty of these:

/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit: WARNING: /etc/chkrootkit.conf is deprecated. Please put your settings in /etc/chkrootkit/chkrootkit.conf instead: /etc/chkrootkit.conf will be ignored in a future release and should be deleted.

May I safely delete that obsoleted config file?

When I compared those two files, the old one contained only 3 configuration lines. Without comments, it was really impossible for me to understand what they were doing. On the opposite side the new file is 88 lines long, very nicely commented. Actually most of the contents are comments.
IMHO it is safe to delete, there were differences on all 3 configuration lines, I better chose to go for those in the new file without any change, just so you know.
sudo rm /etc/chkrootkit.conf

Mails regarding this will no longer bother you.
